# Operation between 2 data frames in R

Tags: r, text, dataframe, nlp

I have this data frame:

```
 word       value
 very good    2 
 this is      2
 we are      -1
 very bad    -2
      . 
      .
      .
```

And:

```
Sentences <- c('good good','very good very bad','we are we are','very good very good very bad')
```

How can I make a data frame that takes the 'score' of each centance:

```
                         Sentences    score
    1                    good good        0
    2           very good very bad        0
    3                we are we are       -2
    4 very good very good very bad        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(Sentences, score=sapply(Sentences, function(x) sum(str_count(x, score$word)*score$value)), row.names = NULL)

                     Sentences score
1                    good good     0
2           very good very bad     0
3                we are we are    -2
4 very good very good very bad     2
```